# How can I build my own Twiml for outbound calls?

Tags: rest-api, integration, cti, twilio

I am trying to build a call center based on Twilio and I wanted to know if we can build out own Call object like below code does in Java:

link: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource

```
    public class Example {
    // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/console
    // DANGER! This is insecure. See http://twil.io/secure
    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "AC4b0f61f6aaa27a4231e6c03be3488178";
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "your_auth_token";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
        Call call = Call.creator(
                new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber("+15558675310"),
                new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber("+15552223214"),
                **new com.twilio.type.Twiml("<Response><Say>Ahoy there!</Say></Response>"))**
            .create();

        System.out.println(call.getSid());
    }
}
```

I know we can use the URL parameter, but I want to dynamically create a Twiml, rather than use a resource that is going to be static.

If we cannot build a Twiml dynamically, and use that to build our call resource, is there any way I can create a dial.xml file dynamically?

Source: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this.

The Twilio Calls resource expects 3 params at minimum:

1. From: The phone number that will be displayed at the contact's end
2. To: The phone number of the contact
3. Url: The absolute URL that returns the TwiML instructions for the call.
4. Twiml: TwiML instructions for the call Twilio will use without fetching Twiml from url parameter. If both twiml and url are provided then twiml parameter will be ignored.

The last param can be passed as a string that contains the actual Twiml Body.

This solved my issue.

Comment: I have an issue with if i use twiml an error happens 'Says unexpected argument twiml I followed the docs but i don't know what to do with that. '